# Why there isn't a symbol that represents Socialism?

Tags: socialism, symbols

While Communism has a very well known and used symbol (hammer and sickle), Socialism doesn't.
Even though Communism and Socialism are somewhat similar they aren't the same, so why doesn't Socialism have a symbol (or if it does, which could be one).
I also thought that the communist symbol purely derived from the USSR flag and that made me think that also other symbols like these came from flags (like the 3rd Reich for Nationalsocialism), but with Capitalism we can somehow imagine one (even though there isn't any specific in flags eccetera.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the premise of the question is true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_heraldry https://www.etsy.com/market/socialist_symbols

Comment: And indeed many of them overlap with communist marks, with different meanings in different cultures, which leads to some complicated semiotics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flag_(politics)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Flag

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28symbolism%29#Socialism_and_social_democracy

Comment: @ohwilleke: the page you link to lists various symbols each country has chosen, but I'm not sure it answers the Q. I don't see any globally recognized symbols there (representing socialism as a whole) TBH.

Comment: @Fizz For much of its history, the "Internationale" was the de facto standard bearing of the global movement and its symbols were the symbols of socialism generally in a way that didn't have a counterpart, for example, in capitalism. Also there doesn't have to be a single consensus symbol for there to be "a symbol that represents socialism". In the same way the cross represents Christianity, but some faiths prefer to display it bare while others prefer to show Jesus on it, while others use the Jesus fish-basically a pun dating to the early Christian church in Greece. All are Christian symbols.

Comment: @timuzhti: yeah, the red rose is probably the closest given what I recall seeing at some social-democracy party gatherings.

Answer (score 17):

Why would there be.  A symbol requires an organisation to design it. The Hammer and Sickle wasn't a communist symbol until adopted by the communist party in Russia.

Political theories, frameworks, or systems don't have an organisation to create a logo, so they don't have one.

Capitalism, democracy, autocracy, monarchy, theocracy, republicanism, none of these have a "symbol" and nor does socialism

Comment: There is also the question "which socialism?". The word today is used to mean such a massive range of political and economic systems ranging from North Korea to the "Nordic model" (basically capitalism but with higher taxes and better social security). Any symbol is going to become associated with one particular answer to that question rather than the entire spectrum.

Comment: Not wanting to nitpick, but monarchists almost always use a crown as their symbol and theocrats usually use symbols of the religion they claim to represent.

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming that you're asking about socialists that don't self-identify as communists, the closest thing nowadays to a quasi-official symbol that you can get for this is probably the [red rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28symbolism%29#Socialism_and_social_democracy). According to one (2018) French [paper](http://histoire-politique.fr/documents/36/autresArticles/pdf/HP36_Varia_FredericCepede_def.pdf) (by Frédéric Cépède) the red rose was used as a symbol, in one form or another, by about half the member parties of the [Party of European Socialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_of_European_Socialists). However, the PES itself doesn't use the rose in its logo.

On the other hand, the [Socialist International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_International) does use it that way since 1979, more precisely in the rose-in-the-fist combo, apparently having adopted that from the French Socialist party, which used that symbol itself since 1971. On the other hand, that paper notes that the combo containing the fist was only adopted by two or three other parties in Europe, so it's not that widespread in that form.

Another symbol that is sometimes used, but apparently has been mostly losing steam in recent decades was plain [red flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flag_(politics))... although the color red is still a favorite in the symbolism of socialist parties.

As for reasons in all these variations, I'd chalk it to the lack of more centralized dogmatism like the (Moscow-controlled) [Communist International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_International) exercised.

Comment: FWTW a search finds a [2002 flag](https://www.fotw.info/flags/eu%7Dpes.html) (supposedly) of PES that does use the rose too, but it's not included in Wikipedia, so I'm not sure how official it was or if they dropped it since then.

Answer (score 1):

*Socialism* is a poorly defined term that may mean many different things, whereas *Communism* or *Nazism* are clearly associated with specific ideologies, "philosophical" and "economical" works, and the regimes that tried to implement these ideologies.

Thus, communists view *socialism* as a transition state from capitalism to communism - in this sense the communist symbols are also the socialist symbols. Indeed, the USSR and its satellites officially proclaimed their economic and social system to be *Developed socialism* (also known as [*Real socialism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_socialism).)

In western Europe *socialism* is a colloquial term used to refer to *social democracy*, which is a *liberal democracy* augmented with various mechanisms for wealth redistribution, such as a social safety net, general healthcare, government run retirement system, etc. In this case *socialism* is really a laymen word used to refer to what is actually a form of capitalism.

Finally, *socialism* is often used as a catch-term to put positive spin on some policies, as opposed to negatively viewed *individualism*, *social Darwinism*, *selfishness*, etc. *Democratic* and *People* is often used in the same way (like in [Democratic People's Republic of North Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea).) Thus, term *Democratic socialism* is viewed as an oxymoron by the communists and as a tautology by western Europeans - which is probably the reason why it is now being rebranded into *social liberalism*. (It is worth noting however, that *Democratic socialism* is also the term used to refer to the [economic system in pre-Thatcher Britain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1793650179), and Margaret Thatcher extensively uses it herself in her autobiography.)

Comment: Indeed yes. The  fasces might well be the ideal symbol for socialism. Except I really can't give you a thumbs-up for saying "various mechanisms for wealth redistribution, such as a social safety net, general healthcare, government run retirement system, etc." is a form of capitalism. It is a form of *mixed* *economy*.

Comment: @BillOnne some European states are indeed *mixed economies*, but not in the sense you propose. I think what is crucial is who owns the means of production (i.e., who produced wealth, not who spends/redistributes it). E.g., in France the energy sector is largely state owned.